# Is there an extension for safari like RightToClick or RightToCopy or some workaround with the same effect?

Tags: safari, web-browser, safari-extensions, javascript

Looking for an extension that will block websites from disabling right click or text selection.

Answer (score 2):

I found [this Safari Extension called Right Click](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/right-click/id1364038646?mt=12).

This extension re-enables the right-click, selection and copy function on website which block those

Answer (score 1):

Blocking right-click in browser is usually accomplished by using JavaScript. To prevent it, you can either:

- Install a JS-blocking plugin (like [JS Blocker](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/42143/js-blocker)).

  It will likely block other scripts from running too, so you need to customise it. Especially if content is also displayed with the usage of scripts.
- Enable **Show Develop menu in menu bar** (in Safari -> Preferences -> Advanceed)

  Expand **Develop** menu and select **Disable JavaScript**.

<sup>Credits to [Dan](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/20428/dan) for the second idea.</sup>

Comment: If you enable the “Develop” Menu (Preferences; Advanced) it’s possible to temporarily disable Javascript once the page is loaded, no extensions required.